# Bluetooth keyboard map are correct for Windows but not for Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, bluetooth, keyboard-layout

I have Ubuntu 20.04 and I recently bought a Joyaccess bluetooth QWERTY keyboard.

It works like a charm on Windows, however when I use it with Ubuntu the keymap is not properly done.

There are some misbehaviours which are getting me on my nerves:

- `Win` and `Alt` keys are swapped.
- `Home` and `End` keys are not working. On the bluetooth keyboard layout, these two keys are placed between the `Enter` and numeric keys, just above the arrows. I have checked the code of these two keys and they are `113` and `114` respectively.

I think the Keyboard is detecting my computer as a Mac and applying some logic. Do you know the easiest way to perform these changes?

**cat /etc/default/keyboard output**

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="es"
XKBVARIANT="winkeys"
XKBOPTIONS="lv3:ralt_switch"

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and show us the output from this command: `cat /etc/default/keyboard`

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson There you are, thank you sir

Answer (score 0):

This is an attempt at a partial answer.

`/etc/default/keyboard` looks good AFAICT, so no explanation there.

As regards the switched keys, you may want to try:

- Install the `gnome-tweaks` package.
- Open *Tweaks* and navigate to *Keyboard & Mouse -> Additional Layout Options -> Alt/Win key behavior*.
- Enable the *Alt is swapped with Win* option.

Comment: I already tried that, but that fixes the problem on the bluetooth keyboard and changes the correct configuration on the built-in keyboard. I am looking for an ad-hoc solution that only changes the bluetooth keyboard configuration